# UK Building co-ordinates web service

Tags: geocoding, web-service, united-kingdom

Within the UK, do any commercial web services offer building level geocoding to a coordinate?  If so what level of accuracy is available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen some spatial data from the [The GeoInformation Group](http://www.geoinformationgroup.co.uk/products/mapping), which has buildings with addresses for some of the larger metro areas. When a colleague of mine last checked with them they did not have a national database of information but were working on extending their cities, AFAIK.